# Word to describe touching someone to call their attention

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

So I'm looking for a word to describe when you touch someone to get their attention.

Example: touching someone shoulder, so they will turn and start a conversation.

Is there a verb that can fit in the sentence: "This persons likes to XXX me a lot" by XXX meaning touching to call for attention.

XXX should be also usable if the person touches you on the back or other parts of the body.

Thanks

Comment: This is tapping on the shoulder.

Comment: Some people might call it "unwanted.".

Comment: Someone *nudges* you to get your attention. Or "This person likes to engage me a lot".

Comment: I like nudges, I think it fits the meaning

Comment: One doesn't *_call their attention_; one _gets their attention_.